Error from pg_stat_bgwriter after upgrade from Postgres v15 to v17
we upgraded our DB systems from Postgres 15 to Postgres 17. Everything is working, but i see those strange errors in the log file of our subscriber (logical replication):
[user=postgres,db=template1,app=[unknown]] ERROR:  column "checkpoints_timed" does not exist at character 8
[user=postgres,db=template1,app=[unknown]] ERROR:  column "buffers_checkpoint" does not exist at character 8

I thought it might be our PgAnalyze monitoring, but deactivating it didn't make the error go away. The statement that throws the error is
SELECT buffers_checkpoint,buffers_clean,buffers_backend,buffers_alloc FROM pg_stat_bgwriter

Where does that come from? Is this something internal? Unlikely, otherwise they would have adjusted the command in Pg 17 as the columns where removed, right?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Does table pg_stat_bgwriter in database template have that column at both ends of the replication? Don't forget schema changes don't get transmitted by logical replication.

@RichardHuxton mmmh, but the table (or view) pg_stat_bgwriter is an internal one. I thought the schema changes are done by the update?

Well, it is worth checking. It is also perhaps worth checking that you aren't directing stats to a different (user) table on the subscribing end. I have a setup where stats get aggregated/summarised from multiple dbs into a custom table

these columns don't exist in this view: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-BGWRITER-VIEW

@FrankHeikens correct. I just checked on both publisher and subscriber and the table doesn't contain those columns. Just like expected. So how can i find out where this SELECT is coming from?

It looks you have monitoring software other than that what you already know about (PgAnalyze).  If some unknown party is logging onto your database as the superuser, you need to tighten you security.
